# Sails Neo4J Create relationship with sails-neo4J

Tags: neo4j, waterline, node-neo4j

I am pretty new to sailsJS and Neo4J, my roadblock is to create relation between two nodes with reference ID.

My Code Sample :

```
    params.id = 'b8995544-02fc-4148-807f-d9c9f0ebd60f';
    var q = [
        'MATCH (w:word{id:'+ JSON.stringify(params.id)+ '}),(a:audiofiles{wordId:'+JSON.stringify(params.id)+'}) CREATE (w)-[r:HASMANY]->(a) RETURN r' 
    ];
    connections[connection].connection.query(q.join(' '), {}).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        cb(null, result);
        }, function (err) {
        cb(err, null);
        console.log(err);
    });
```

My Output is something:

```
     [ 'MATCH (w:word{id:"faedcf89-b323-48f4-9c29-f4396822f83c"}),(a:audiofiles{wordId:"faedcf89-b323-48f4-9c29-f4396822f83c"}) 
    CREATE (w)-[r:HASMANY]->(a) RETURN r' ]

    { columns: [ 'r' ],
 data: [],
   status:
      { httpCode: '200',
        statusCode: '200',
        httpMessage: 'OK',
        httpDescription: 'Request succeeded without error' } }
```

Even then it is not creating relation at Neo4J any issue, I am unable to debug at this framework. Can any one help me what is the root cause which doesnt creating relation between these.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you see an issue when you get an http-200 back, which is good.

If you mean that `data` is empty -> it would contain the newly created relationship's properties, and as you have none, it will not contain data.
You can also return `id(r)` or `type(r)`

In this case it might just be that you have a typo somewhere either in your id. Or property-name or whatever. Try to run the query manually if your MATCH actually finds the `word` and the `audiofiles`. (Btw. labels are usually capitalized, not lowercase)

You should use parameters!

```
params.id = 'b8995544-02fc-4148-807f-d9c9f0ebd60f';
var q = 
    'MATCH (w:word{id:{id}}), (a:audiofiles{wordId:{id}}) CREATE (w)-[r:HASMANY]->(a) RETURN r';
connections[connection].connection.query(q, params).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    cb(null, result);
    }, function (err) {
    cb(err, null);
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I have gone through written code, but i didnt found any Typo error in the above code. not able to debug the issue even.